# How to get all data combining two models in laravel

Tags: laravel

I am using Eloquent and I want to get all data combining two models.

I have two models `Courseoffer` and `Courseoffer_payment`.
Inside `Courseoffer` model I have this function:

```
public function payment()
{
    return $this->hasone('App\Models\Courseoffer_payment');
}
```

And this is my query :

```
return Courseoffer::findorfail(10)->payment;
```

This will give me data of `Courseoffer_payment` model associated with id 10 but I want all data for `Courseoffer` as well as `Courseoffer_payment` associated with id 10.

Comment: You will need to do an inverse of the relationship `hasOne` on one model class and `belongsTo` on the other model class

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `with` instead like :

```
return Courseoffer::with('payment')->findorfail(10);
```

That will return the Courseoffer 10 instance with the payment information.

Comment: thank you.it worked fine. what if i have another model like Fee with function fee and want to join 3 of these.?

Comment: You can use the comma separator like `Courseoffer::with('payment', 'another_relation')->findorfail(10);`

Comment: Hi, Please If this answer is what you're looking for Mark it as the correct answer For the future readers.